# How to connect Verilog module's output to several wires?

Tags: verilog, output

Say I have a `module foo(in1,in2,out);` and `module mad1(in,out); module mad2(in,out); module mad3(in,out);`
While instantiating these modules I want to use the output (`out`) of `foo` as an input to each of the mad modules.
Something like this:

```
input in1,in2;
output out1,out2,out3;
wire w_out;
foo i_foo(.in1(in1),.in2(in2),.out(w_out));
mad1 i_mad1(,in(w_out),.out(out1));
mad2 i_mad2(,in(w_out),.out(out2));
mad3 i_mad3(,in(w_out),.out(out3));
```

Is that approach correct or should I save the output of the foo module to a register?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach is perfectly correct.